# Visual Studio Android Emulator optimizing apps loop

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.forms

I have three computers (2 i7, all old ones and 1 i5 6880).

Only on that i5, and only for android lollipop, the Visual Studio Android Emulator is stuck on a eternal loop: Android logo -> Optimizing App x/67 -> Reboot.

Android 4.4 works just fine.

Have reinstalled Windows and Visual Studio 3x =\

Is there someone with the same problem?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue on API 21, 22 and 23.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved:
In Hyper-V manager, delete all saved state (if any), go to processor settings, expand it and choose compatibility mode (check "Migrate to a physical computer with a different processsor version).

Comment: This exact thing happened when trying to install Google Play Services with Android 6.0 Marshmallow and Genymotion. Your suggestion worked like a charm once I encountered the 'optimizing app' loop!

Comment: I wouldn't use Genymotion (nor Visual Studio Android Emulator). The google official emulator with HAXM is fast enough, has command-line support and have official Google Play images. Tired of #$% or freemium products =\